# Understand 'callback' in computer programming

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I cannot interpret the jargon 'callback' in computer programming intuitively.

The definition of 'callback' in Dictionary:

In collins dictionary, [Callback definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/callback)

> A callback is an occasion when you are asked to return for a second interview for a job, or a second audition for a part in a show.

In telecommunications [Callback (telecommunications) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(telecommunications))

> In telecommunications, a callback or call-back occurs when the originator of a call is immediately called back in a second call as a response.

In conlusion, the keyword of 'callback' is 'second'.

As to its usage in computer_programming,it's difficult to figure out what the 'second' references to.

[Quote from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))In computer programming, a callback is any executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at a given time.

Amongst the sentence, 'call back (execute) the argument at a given time.' So the keyword 'second' refers to the 'argument'.
Nevertheless,when executed, it's the first time of the argument being called.

A trivial python code exmaple from [Callback (computer programming) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))

```
>>> def my_square(val):
...     """ the callback """
...     return val ** 2
...
>>> def caller(val, func):
...     return func(val)

>>> caller(2, my_square)
>>> 2
```

Reference to arguement '2',it is called for one single time during the process instead of second return.
How to understand the 'callback' then?

Comment: I don't particularly like the term "callback" either.  I feel like it's more a "reference forward" than a "reference back" -- but it is what it is.  Sometimes you have to use the terminology someone else chose for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a domain-specific usage (which has a very well-established meaning in the context of software).

Comment: It's hard to understand actually. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I remove it to stackoverflow,but have no reputation to del @FumbleFingers

Comment: Jose: I just googled **define callback**. The first link returned was to [Callback (computer programming) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), which kicks off with: *In computer programming, a callback is any executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at a given time.* Assuming you know anything at all about programming, how is that hard to understand? If you *don't*, why would you want to start with such an obscure concept?

Comment: I am jumping to reach, Sir@FumbleFingers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a callback is any executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at a given time.

*Back* when used phrasally can mean something like "doing this in response to something."

Given a traditional imperative programming paradigm, typically you are writing a list of instructions and using functions to execute steps in an algorithm, and these steps are perfomed one-by-one and in order, and the next step starts when the current one completes.

Callbacks reverse this and allow a more asynchronous model to exist - your instruction is doing something like "dispatching" a task to be actually called later, rather than representing an atomic task that will complete before the next one starts.

So you can think of it as similar to a dispatcher needing a field worker to do something, and he/she leaves a message on his/her phone.  The dispatcher then goes on to do other things while waiting for the *call back*.  When the field worker is ready, the worker will *call* the dispatcher *back* (returning the call).

I am not a programmer, so I suppose it may be in vogue to describe any function passed as a parameter or argument as a callback, even if things are working synchronously.  E.g. specifying a function to perform comparison in a sort routine.

Another example: when you borrow something, another way to express returning it is *giving it back*.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a programming question than a language one, but the definition works

> In telecommunications, a callback or call-back occurs when the
>   originator of a call is immediately called back in a second call as a
>   response.

In this case, the first call is to the function `caller()`, which then makes the call to `my_square()` in response.  That call to `my_square()` is the second call.

Comment: I'm not sure ***immediately** called back* is relevant to the normal use of callbacks in programming. I have on occasion used callbacks to handle "error" situations which might *never* be called.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that April and Winnie are talking (via telephone).  April asks Winnie to call her back.  She gives a telephone number to call back on.  This number is sometimes called a "callback number".

**April:**  Hello.
**Winnie:**  Hi, this is Winnie.
**April:**   How are things going for you?
**Winnie:**  Good, but I'm kind of busy right now.  Can I give you a call back later?
**April:**   Sure.  My number is (234) 555-6789.  Give me a call when you get a chance.
**Winnie:**  Will do.  Have a great day!

Imagine that your application is making a request (call) to the Windows API:

**Application:**  Hi, this is Application ABCD.  I want to play a practical joke using one of the windows.  Please give a call back to this "practical joke" function in my program.  When you call back, give the handle of a window to the "practical joke" function.  The "practical joke" function will tell you if I have had enough fun, or if you should call back again with the handle of another window.
**Windows:** Will do.

**Windows:**  Hi, practical joke.  Here's a window handle.  I hope you like it.
**Practical joke:** Ha, ha!.  Give me another!
**Windows:**  Hi, practical joke.  Here's another window handle.  I hope you like it.
**Practical joke:** Ha, ha, ha!  That's enough.
**Windows:**  Whoo! I can do something else now.

You really can call the Windows API like this.  Your "function call" asks the [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908392.aspx) function to call a function in your application.  In other words, the Windows API is calling you back.  You have to tell EnumWindows what function to call.  That function (the "practical joke" function in this example) is similar to the callback number ((234) 555-6789 in the telephone example).  It is often called a "callback function".